# textarea knockout attr binding for row attribute dont work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want change height of texterea by knockout 2.3.0

I bind the value of the texterea to "FileData" observable field
and want the texterea rows attribute will changed to the count of rows in "FileData"

the value bind works fine but attr don't work

```js
var self = this;
self.FileData = ko.observable("");

self.lineBreakCount = function(str) { 
  /* counts \n */ 
  try { 
    return ((str.match(/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*/gi).length)) + 1; 
  } catch (e) {
    return 0; 
  } 
}

self.buttonClick = function () {
$.get(url, {  })
.success(function (serverData) { self.FileData(serverData);})
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-bind="click: buttonClick">Click Me</button>
<textarea readonly="readonly" data-bind="value: FileData, attr: { 'rows': lineBreakCount(FileData)}"></textarea>
```

Comment: Your `lineBreakCount` could be an computed observable:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html.  :-)

Comment: this answer worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Your `lineBreakCount` expects a `string`, but you're passing it an `observable` that *contains* a `string`.

To fix this, unwrap your observable either in the binding (`lineBreakCount(FileData())`), or in the method (`str().match`)

```js
var VM = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.FileData = ko.observable("");

  self.lineBreakCount = function(str) {
    /* counts \n */
    try {
      return ((str.match(/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*/gi).length)) + 1;
    } catch (e) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  self.buttonClick = function() {};
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: buttonClick">Click Me</button>
<textarea data-bind="textInput: FileData, attr: { 'rows': lineBreakCount(FileData())}"></textarea>
```

Comment: for working I add bind function: attr: { 'rows': lineBreakCount.bind($data,DriverData())